# Desabilitar botão Jquery no Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Eu quero que, durante a requisição ajax, o botão seja desabilitado e apareça o icone de carregando.
Eu fiz o seguinte script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Clicar no botão deletar selecionadas
   $('#deleteSelecionados').click( function () {
       //Desabilita o botao
       $("#deleteSelecionados").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       //Mostra icone de carregando
       $("#loadIcon").css('visibility','visible');
       //Solicitação ajax
       jQuery.ajax({
            url: strUrl,
            success: function(json) {
                 // qualquer coisa

            },
             async:false
         });    
       //Habilita botao
       $("#deleteSelecionados").removeAttr("disabled");
       //remove icone
       $("#loadIcon").css('visibility','hidden');

    });
 });
```

O processo funciona corretamente no FireFox mas no Chorme quando executado não ocorre nada, quando eu rodo com o debug do javascrip pelo chrome ele funciona perfeitamente desabilitando o botão e mostrando o icone. A sensação é que ele não atualiza a tela durante o processo normal, apenas quando esta no modo de debug.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui reproduzir o problema. Uma forma um pouco melhor de realizar esse processo que está fazendo pode ser a seguinte:

```js
$(function(){

  $('#deleteSelecionados').on('click', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        icon = $('#loadIcon');
    
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      beforeSend: function(){
        self.attr('disabled', 'true');
        icon.css('visibility','visible');
      },
      success: function(json){
         // faz algo
      },
      complete: function(){
        self.removeAttr('disabled');
        icon.css('visibility','hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#loadIcon { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='deleteSelecionados'>Deletar selecionados</button>
<img id='loadIcon' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/agofk.gif'/>
```

A função `beforeSend` será executada antes de fazer a requisição. Como você precisa desabilitar o botão e exibir a imagem somente na requisição ajax, pode ser o momento de fazer isso.

A função `complete` será executada independente do resultado terminar com sucesso ou erro. Então você pode utilizar esse momento para habilitar novamente o botão e esconder a imagem que indica o carregamento dos dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, mas ainda não resolveu o problema!

Comment: Não entendi, por que a marcou como correta se não resolveu o problema Luciano?

Comment: Fazendo da forma que você sugeriu e removendo a clasula async:false. funcionou corretamente.